# cakephp3のキャッシュエンジンフォールバック

Tags: cakephp

キャッシュエンジンフォールバックがやりたいと思い、config/app.phpで下記のように設定
しているのですが、キャッシュサーバーをダウンさせると書き込みエラーになってしまいます。
何が原因かおわかりになる方いらっしゃいますか？

ちなみにcake_core_fallbackの設定自体は間違っておらず、これを_cake_core_として設定すると問題なく動作します。

なお、CakePHPのバージョンは、3.5.11を使用しております。よろしくお願いします。

```
'_cake_core_' => [
    'className' => 'Cake\Cache\Engine\MemcachedEngine',
    'prefix' => 'myapp_cake_core_',
    'duration' => '+1 years',
    'servers' => [キャッシュサーバーホスト名：ポート番号],
    'username' => 'memcached',
    'fallback' => 'cake_core_fallback',
],
'cake_core_fallback' => [
    'className' => 'File',
    'prefix' => 'myapp_cake_core_',
    'path' => CACHE . 'persistent/',
    'serialize' => true,
    'duration' => '+1 years',
    'mask' => 0664,
],
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/111711

Comment: 利用しているCakePHPのバージョンを記入してください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！CakePHPのバージョンは3.5.11になります。